# LESS - Button Gradient as Mixin Breaks Hover Style

Tags: css-selectors, less, mixins

I moved some gradient button styles into a mixin and now the hover styling is incorrect. The hover state should apply a background offset with the gradient over the top but when used as a mixin it is being applied in the reverse order i.e., the offset is applied on top of the gradient, making the button look like it is two different solid colors. What's the correct way to apply these styles using a mixin?

***Styles***

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: hsl(98, 35%, 73%) !important;
  color: #333 !important;
  .btn-gradient(#ebf3e6, #b3d2a2);
}
```

***Mixin***

```
.btn-gradient(@startColor, @endColor) {
  border-color: @endColor @endColor hsl(98, 35%, 68%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=@startColor, endColorstr=@endColor);
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@startColor), to(@endColor));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, @startColor), color-stop(100%, @endColor));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
  background-image: linear-gradient(@startColor, @endColor);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  &:hover {
    background-position: 0 -15px;
  }
}
```

***Mixin hover***

[image: hover mixin]

***No mixin hover***

[image: no mixin hover]

Comment: Mixins do not reorder any styles/properties, so essentially you get what you wrote. To get some constructive/helpful answer I suggest you to put more details on "1. CSS I want 2. CSS I get instead" into the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing background-repeat: repeat-x; from the mixin.